# Capture Current Desktop Session using Boot Diagnostics

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine

I'd like to monitor the desktop sessions of Windows 10 and Windows Server VMs in Azure. I am able to view the lock screens of both using Boot Diagnostics, but cannot get the signed in user's view to appear.

The VMs are being used for labs and instructional purposes; Boot Diagnostics is being considered as a non-intrusive manner of getting the current screen of a student.

Is there a way to log in and view the desktop session through Boot Diagnostics, or is there an alternative service that can be used to achieve a similar result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the RDP shadow function.

See https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/292190/how-to-shadow-a-terminal-server-session-without-prompt-for-approval

To connect remotely you can use:

```
query session /server:[hostname-of-VM]
```

Then call the RDP client as follows:

```
mstsc.exe /v:[hostname-of-VM] /shadow:[id]
```

Comment: This is a valid alternative. I have found that you can use Windows autologon which solves the problem within Boot Diagnostics.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Autologon would enable this scenario, as Boot Diagnostics would then capture the screenshots from the user's logged in session.

As it does require keeping credentials in the registry in plain text, security considerations and appropriate user permissions need to be reviewed.

https://superuser.com/questions/499724/auto-login-windows-server-2012